# Problema con duplicidad de imágenes al momento de insertar en la tabla de la BD con Php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

Tengo el siguiente problema. Tengo un formulario que se envía al controlador **`solicitudp.php`** , dicho formulario tiene algunos campos de texto y también tiene subida múltiple de imágenes, pero cuando se inserta el formulario en la base de datos, las imágenes se duplican, tanto en la ruta de la carpeta donde se almacenan las imágenes, como en la columna `imagenes` de la tabla `solicitudes`; así mismo en la tabla `registros`, pero en la tabla `registros` pude darme cuenta que se tienen 2 registros diferentes una con **`id` 0** y otro con el registro del ***id_solicitud***; entonces obviamente el duplicado es con el `id` 0. Pero ya probé varios códigos para ver el por qué de la duplicidad.

En la ruta se guardan, por ejemplo, si subo 3 imágenes por solicitud se guardan 6, pero como cada una tiene una fecha y hora exacta entonces es como si no se copiaran una con otra.

El problema solo es con las imágenes que se duplican, con los demás registros no sucede. A continuación les muestro tanto el HTML donde tengo el input para las imágenes, como el Javascript para previsualizar las imágenes en el formulario así como el ajax para enviarlas al controlador y también todo el código que tengo en **`solicitudp.php`**. Por su colaboración de antemano muy agradecido!

```
<div class="col-md-6">
 <div class="form-group">
  <label for="imagenes" style="color: indigo">
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></i> Imágenes de Garantias que deja el cliente:
  </label>
  <input type="file" class="form-control" id="imagenes" name="imagenes[]" multiple>
  <div id="vista-previa" style="margin-top: 10px;"></div>
  <div id="respuesta"></div>
 </div>
</div>

<script>
  $(function(){
    $("#imagenes").on("change", function(){
      /* Limpiar vista previa */
      // $("#vista-previa").html('');
      var archivos = document.getElementById('imagenes').files;
      var navegador = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
      
      /* Crear objeto FormData */
      var formData = new FormData();
      
      /* Recorremos todos los archivos subidos */
      for (var x = 0; x < archivos.length; x++) {
        /* Validamos el tamaño del archivo */
        var size = archivos[x].size;
        var type = archivos[x].type;
        var name = archivos[x].name;
        
        if (size > 5 * 1024 * 1024) {
          $("#vista-previa").append("<p style='color:green'>El archivo " + name + " supera el tamaño máximo permitido de 5 MB</p>");
        } else if (type != 'image/jpeg' && type != 'image/jpg' && type != 'image/png' && type != 'image/gif') {
          $("#vista-previa").append("<p style='color:green'>El archivo " + name + " no tiene un formato de imagen válido. Solo se permiten archivos JPEG, PNG y JPG</p>");
        } else {
          /* Agregar archivo al objeto FormData */
          formData.append('imagenes[]', archivos[x]);
          
          var objeto_url = navegador.createObjectURL(archivos[x]);
          $("#vista-previa").append("<img src='" + objeto_url + "' width='150px' height='150px' >");
        }
      }
      
      /* Enviar imágenes mediante Ajax */
      $.ajax({
        url: '../c/solicitudp.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(response) {
          // Procesar la respuesta del servidor
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
          // Manejar el error en caso de que ocurra
        }
      });
    });   
  });
</script>
```

**solicitudp.php**

```
<?php

require_once '../cfg/cnx.php';

// obtener el número de serie correlativo
$sql = "SELECT MAX(numero_serie) AS ultimo_numero_serie FROM solicitudes";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$ultimo_numero_serie = $stmt->fetchColumn();
$numero_serie = $ultimo_numero_serie + 1;

if($numero_serie === NULL) {
   $numero_serie = "0000001";
}
echo "Numero de serie: " . $numero_serie; // mensaje de prueba

// guardar datos del formulario en variables
$fecha_solicitud = $_POST['fecha_solicitud'];
$estado = $_POST['estado'];
$nombreu = $_POST['nombreu'];
$nombrec = $_POST['nombrec'];
$dpi = $_POST['dni'];
$edad = $_POST['edad'];
$nom_padre = $_POST['nom_padre'];
$nom_madre = $_POST['nom_madre'];
$nom_esposa = $_POST['nom_esposa'];
$direccion_casa = $_POST['direccion_casa'];
$direccion_trabajo = $_POST['direccion_trabajo'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$phone2 = $_POST['phone2'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

var_dump($stmt->errorInfo());


// Insertar los datos en la tabla 'solicitudes'
$sql = "INSERT INTO solicitudes (numero_serie, fecha_solicitud, estado, nombreu, nombrec, dni, edad, nom_padre, nom_madre, nom_esposa,  direccion_casa, direccion_trabajo, phone, phone2, email)
        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([
    $numero_serie,  $_POST['fecha_solicitud'], $_POST['estado'], $_POST['nombreu'], $_POST['nombrec'], $_POST['dni'], $_POST['edad'], 
    $_POST['nom_padre'], $_POST['nom_madre'], $_POST['nom_esposa'], $_POST['direccion_casa'], $_POST['direccion_trabajo'], 
    $_POST['phone'], $_POST['phone2'], $_POST['email'] ]);

var_dump($stmt->errorInfo());

// Guardar las imágenes en la carpeta destino y las rutas en la tabla 'solicitudes'

if (isset($_FILES['imagenes'])) {
    $ruta_destino = "../storage/garantias/"; // Carpeta destino para guardar las imágenes
    $num_imagenes = count($_FILES['imagenes']['name']); // Obtener el número de imágenes seleccionadas
    
    $formatos_validos = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif'); // Formatos válidos
    
    // Obtener el ID de la última solicitud insertada
    $id_solicitud = $pdo->lastInsertId();
    
    $imagenes_a_insertar = array(); // Array para almacenar las rutas de las imágenes a insertar
    
    for ($i = 0; $i < $num_imagenes; $i++) {
        $imagen_temporal = $_FILES['imagenes']['tmp_name'][$i];
        $imagen_nombre = $_FILES['imagenes']['name'][$i];
        $imagen_extension = strtolower(pathinfo($imagen_nombre, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)); // Obtener extensión de la imagen
        
        // Verificar formato válido
        if (!in_array($imagen_extension, $formatos_validos)) {
            echo "<script>alert('El formato de la imagen $imagen_nombre no es válido.');</script>";
            continue;
        }
        
        // Generar un nombre único para la imagen
        $fecha_hora_actual = date('d-m-Y_H:i:s');
        $nombre_asignado = "garantia_" . $fecha_hora_actual . "_" . $imagen_nombre;
        
        // Mover la imagen del directorio temporal al directorio destino
        $ruta_destino_completa = $ruta_destino . $nombre_asignado;
        if (move_uploaded_file($imagen_temporal, $ruta_destino_completa)) {
            $imagenes_a_insertar[] = $ruta_destino_completa; // Agregar la ruta de la imagen al array
            
            // Insertar un registro en la tabla 'registros'
            $sql = "INSERT INTO registros (solicitud_id, imagen_nombre) VALUES (?, ?)";
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindValue(1, $id_solicitud, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindValue(2, $nombre_asignado, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->execute();

            if ($stmt->rowCount() <= 0) {
                error_log("Error al insertar el registro en la tabla registros", 0);
            }
        } else {
            echo "<script>alert('Error al mover la imagen al directorio destino.');</script>";
        }
    }
    
    if (!empty($imagenes_a_insertar)) {
        // Verificar si las imágenes ya existen en la columna 'imagenes' de la tabla 'solicitudes'
        $sql = "SELECT imagenes FROM solicitudes WHERE id = ?";
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindValue(1, $id_solicitud, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $imagenes_anteriores = $row['imagenes'];
        
        // Filtrar las imágenes nuevas para evitar duplicados
        $imagenes_nuevas = array_diff($imagenes_a_insertar, explode(',', $imagenes_anteriores));
        
        // Agregar las nuevas imágenes a las imágenes anteriores
        $imagenes_actualizadas = array_merge(explode(',', $imagenes_anteriores), $imagenes_nuevas);
        
        // Actualizar la columna 'imagenes' en la tabla 'solicitudes'
        $imagenes_actualizadas_str = implode(',', $imagenes_actualizadas);
        $sql = "UPDATE solicitudes SET imagenes = ? WHERE id = ?";
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindValue(1, $imagenes_actualizadas_str, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(2, $id_solicitud, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();

        if ($stmt->rowCount() <= 0) {
            echo "<script>alert('Las imágenes no pudieron ser ingresadas en la columna imagenes de la tabla solicitudes.');</script>";
        }
        
        // Insertar un registro en la tabla 'registros'
        $sql = "INSERT INTO registros (solicitud_id, imagen_nombre) VALUES (?, ?)";
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindValue(1, $id_solicitud, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue(2, $nombre_asignado, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();

        if ($stmt->rowCount() <= 0) {
            error_log("Error al insertar el registro en la tabla registros", 0);
        }
    } else {
        echo "<script>alert('Error al mover la imagen al directorio destino.');</script>";
    }
    
    
    // Redirigir después de guardar todas las imágenes
    header('Location: ../v/cind.php');
    exit();
}
```

Así es como se muestra en la tabla registros tanto con el id 0 como el id de la solicitud

```
0  | garantia_31-05-2023_02:39:26_1.jpg
0  | garantia_31-05-2023_02:39:26_2.png
0  | garantia_31-05-2023_02:39:26_3.png
0  | garantia_31-05-2023_02:39:26_4.png
13 | garantia_31-05-2023_02:39:44_1.jpg
13 | garantia_31-05-2023_02:39:44_2.png
13 | garantia_31-05-2023_02:39:45_3.png
13 | garantia_31-05-2023_02:39:45_4.png
```

Comment: El problema es que el código se estaría lanzando a cada cambio en el input que recoge las imágenes, en vez de esto: `$("#imagenes").on("change"` pon un botón `Enviar` que será pulsado una sola vez, cuando todas las imágenes hayan sido recogidas, y dentro del listener de ese botón recoges todo en un FormData para enviarlo una sola vez al servidor.